# Email validation - special characters "dit" Python 2.7

Tags: python

I need some help here with assigning full email address extracted from the string.
Email may or may not has a "."  in it's prefix. But if there is, it must be printed.

```
>>> playString = "user.name@my-domain.com              active      06/07/19 14:34  20200424185622."
>>> matched = re.match(r'(\w+\.)(\w+)@(\w+\.com)', playString)
>>> print(matched)
None
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract the whole e-mail address, I'd suggest doing it this way:

```
matched = re.search(r'(?:\w+\.)?\w+@[\w+\.\-]+', playString)
address = matched.group()
```

`(?:\w+\.)?` means that the whole `user.` part is optional (a question mark after any item - in this case, a non-grouping parentheses - is a short for `{0,1}` ie. "0 or 1 occurences").

Comment: I appreciate it "Blotosmetek" !!!!   This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The hyphen in `my-domain.com` wouldn't be matched by the `\w` pattern. You would have to use `[\w-]` instead. In case you expect other characters in the email you will have to add those to the character class as well.

So, the new code would look like this

```
playString = "user.name@my-domain.com              active      06/07/19 14:34  20200424185622."
matched = re.match(r'(\w+\.)(\w+)@([\w-]+\.com)', playString)
print(matched.groups())  # outputs: ('user.', 'name', 'my-domain.com')
```

Also you might want to use `re.search` instead of `re.match` in case you would like to match emails not just at the start of the string.